# Jenkins can't execute make

Tags: jenkins, makefile, jenkins-pipeline

I am writing a pipeline using the declarative approach and shell commands in jenkins. I clone a repo and cd into it where there is a Makefile and want to run a make command as below:

```
make build something
```

but jenkins fails with this error:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/first-test-run@tmp/durable-135bda8c/script.sh: 9: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/first-test-run@tmp/durable-135bda8c/script.sh: make: not found
```

What I have to do?

Comment: install make on the jenkins server

Comment: Thank you it solved the problem but why you didn't post it as an answer so I can accept it as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install make on the jenkins server